# Handle error on user authentication with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase conecction to my React Native app, and I authenticate an user via email and password. However, each time a user enters a correct email and password, it stills shows me the alert I programmed to show whenever a user inputs a wrong email/password, then it redirects the user to the next page, showing that the user authentication was succesful.

What can I do to prevent the alert from showing up when an user authentication was sucessful?
Here's my code

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.username, this.state.password).catch(
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          'Incorrect data',
          [
            { text: 'Ok' }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        )
).then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Age'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    try {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Age'));
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
       Alert.alert(
          error,
          'Incorrect data',
          [
            { text: 'Ok' }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        )
    }
```

Comment: I tried, but now the problem is that if a user inputs an incorrect email/password, the ```Alert``` message does not appear.

Comment: I made a mistake in above code Ive corrected it, Now try, It will work for sure